# Electron cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'minimize')

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

I tried making an app in electron, but got stuck on a problem I cannot figure out how to solve. It's about minimizing the app. I have `index.html` where's the button for it, then `window.js` where is the event listener. The code of `window.js` looks like this:

```js
const minus = document.getElementById("minimize");
const close = document.getElementById("close-app");

minus.addEventListener("click", minimize);
close.addEventListener("click", close_app);

function minimize(){

    app.window.minimize();

}
function close_app(){

    app.window.close();

}
```

Then I have `preload.js`, I guess everyone who has ever worked in electron knows what that is. Again the code of `preload.js` looks like this:

```js
const { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } = require("electron");

const API = {
    window: {
        minimize: () => ipcRenderer.send("app/minimize"),
        close: () => ipcRenderer.send("app/close"),
    }
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("app", API);
```

And then lastly I have `index.js` here.

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');


// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
// eslint-disable-next-line global-require
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 800,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    frame: false,
    resizable: false,
    maximizable: false,
    fullscreenable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname +  '/backend/preload.js'),            
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
    },
  });

  win.on("moved", (e) => {
    console.log(win.getBounds())
    
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, '/app/index.html'));

  // Open the DevTools.
  win.webContents.openDevTools();
};



// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

ipcMain.on("app/minimize", () => {
  win.minimize();
}
);

ipcMain.on("app/close", () => {
  app.quit();
}
);


// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and import them here.
```

This may look messy, but I will try to explain it. The problem is I cannot use `win.minimize();` in

```js
ipcMain.on("app/minimize", () => {
  win.minimize();
}
);
```

but everywhere else I can. I saw somewhere that it's because of `nodeIntegration: false,` but since it's more secure being false, I don't really want to change that. I tried looking everywhere and tried to do pretty much everything I could, but I still couldn't figure it out. The solution is probably so easy I will question my coding skills after understanding it...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a scoping issue.

Within your `index.js` file, the `win` variable must be defined outside the `createWindow()` function. Only doing this will allow you access to `win` within the `ipcMain.on("app/minimize")` method call.

1. Define the variable in the global scope. This will also prevent garbage collect of your (primary) window when your application is at idle for a long period of time.
2. Return `win` at the end of your `createWindow()` function so its instance is transferred to the global scope variable.

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let win;

if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
    app.quit();
}

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1000,
        height: 800,
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        frame: false,
        resizable: false,
        maximizable: false,
        fullscreenable: false,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'backend/preload.js'),            
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
        },
    });

    win.on('moved', (e) => {
        console.log(win.getBounds())
    })

    win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'app/index.html'))
        .then(() => { win.webContents.openDevTools(); })

    return win;
};


app.on('ready', () => {
    win = createWindow();
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

ipcMain.on('app/minimize', () => {
    win.minimize();
});

ipcMain.on('app/close', () => {
    app.quit();
});
```

Some notes:

> - Tweaked the use of [`path.join`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathjoinpaths) in your `webPreferences -> preload` line to use a comma instead of using the `+` operator. Leading slashes are not required as `path.join` adds them.
> - Used method chaining to `openDevTools()` following the loading of your `index.html` file.